# My computer set my external hard disk as read-only after I upgraded it to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, permissions, external-hdd, usb-drive

I have an HP Compaq 6910p that I upgrade into 11.10 a month ago. It works nicely with only one disability so far. I can't change anything in my external hard disk. It is connected through a USB 3.0.

I can read it in my computer, but in the properties it said that the permission is read-only, and I can't change it. So I can only copy files from it. It sucks because I need to do a lot of things with it. Help me please...

Comment: If any of these answers "answered" your question please accept one of them. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem...

I had `ntfs-3g` installed. In my case Ubuntu removed it? of course i am assuming you have an `NTFS` `EXT-HDD`

please copy/paste this into gnome-terminal to install ntfs-3g:

```
 sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Or via the Ubuntu Software Center. Just search for `ntfs-3g`

Answer (score 1):

Try using Nautilus as root: go to terminal and type "sudo nautilus."

Change the permission properties from there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have succeeded to access my external hard disk after installing ntfs-3g